# How does pytorch calculate matrix pairwise distance? Why isn't 'self' distance not zero?

Tags: python, pytorch, pairwise-distance

If this is a naive question, please forgive me, my test code like this:

```
import torch
from torch.nn.modules.distance import PairwiseDistance

list_1 = [[1., 1.,],[1., 1.]]
list_2 = [[1., 1.,],[2., 1.]]

mtrxA=torch.tensor(list_1)
mtrxB=torch.tensor(list_2)

print "A-B distance     :",PairwiseDistance(2).forward(mtrxA, mtrxB)
print "A 'self' distance:",PairwiseDistance(2).forward(mtrxA, mtrxA)
print "B 'self' distance:",PairwiseDistance(2).forward(mtrxB, mtrxB)
```

Result:

```
A-B distance     : tensor([1.4142e-06, 1.0000e+00])
A 'self' distance: tensor([1.4142e-06, 1.4142e-06])
B 'self' distance: tensor([1.4142e-06, 1.4142e-06])
```

Questions are:

1. How does pytorch calculate pairwise distance? Is it to calculate row vectors distance?
2. Why isn't 'self' distance 0?

---

**Update**

After changing list_1 and list_2 to this:

```
list_1 = [[1., 1.,1.,],[1., 1.,1.,]]
list_2 = [[1., 1.,1.,],[2., 1.,1.,]]
```

Result becomes:

```
A-B distance     : tensor([1.7321e-06, 1.0000e+00])
A 'self' distance: tensor([1.7321e-06, 1.7321e-06])
B 'self' distance: tensor([1.7321e-06, 1.7321e-06])
```

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the documentation of [`nn.PairWiseDistance`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.PairwiseDistance), pytorch expects two 2D tensors of `N` vectors in `D` dimensions, and computes the distances between the `N` pairs.

Why "self" distance is not zero - probably because of [floating point precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/1714410) and because of `eps = 1e-6`.

Comment: ,thanks,I want to know how it is calculated?and I updated questions

Answer (score 0):

according to https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/functional.py

```
Computes the p-norm distance between every pair of row vectors in the input.
```

Comment: yes, but **how** is the calculation is carried out?

Comment: @Shai,sorry,I didn't get it clear enough,when I say "calculation",I want to know what kinds of calculation on what kind of elments,and "Computes the p-norm distance between every pair of row vectors in the input" told me that the p-norm distance will be calculated on corresponded row vectors.